# How do I force pods to not restart so I can investigate logs?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod that is part of a deployment. For some reason, at random intervals, the pod terminates and a new pod is created. I wish to investigate this with the help of logs. However, due to the deletion of older pod, I'm unable to fetch my logs.

Since, they are part of a deployment, I am unable to change the restartPolicy to Never.

Comment: One option is to capture the logs to a file while the pod is running (`kubectl logs -f mypod > logs.txt`). When the pod restarts, you will have the logs locally for inspection.

Comment: If the Pod is restarting, then `kubectl logs ... --previous` will show you the previous container's output.  But if the Pod is getting deleted and recreated, it's a little unlikely anything actually in the container code could cause this.

Comment: Thanks. @DavidMaze , my pod is getting deleted and recreated.